# Why Png Compression doesn't change destination size (C++)? OpenCV VS2010

Tags: c++, image, visual-studio-2010, opencv

I have tested this code with various values from `compression_params.push_back(1);` to `compression_params.push_back(9);` but the PNG image always has same size. 1950x1080 (contains screenshot of Google map - not the satellite photo) has 2,36 MB (2 477 230 bytes. Is this normal is takes so much. I thought png images are small size if they do not contain photos.

```
vector<int> compression_params;
compression_params.push_back(CV_IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION);
compression_params.push_back(1);

try {
    imwrite("RGB_1.png", source, compression_params);
}
catch (runtime_error& ex) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Exception converting image to PNG format: %s\n", ex.what());
    return 1;
}
```

Why is it? Also I cannot find out how to create the PNG object in memory (to keep the encode data in buffer). This means, I would like to save more images into one file (e.g database) so I need to convert into buffer and then save add buffer to file. Is it possible to do it usin OpenCV? Your tips welcome.

I think PNG should support some feature where the algorithm auto-selects background color, so if you see some cv::Scallar(200,200,200) takes too many place on the image, the algorithm could set it as background color and it is removed from the image so the image should take small place. So when it takes same size as regular PNG or even more, that doesn't give any sense.

Comment: "Also I cannot find out how to create the PNG object in memory from Mat image." -- where did you look? [`imencode`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html#imencode) is documented on the same page as `imwrite`.

Comment: "The function compresses the image and stores it in the memory buffer that is resized to fit the result." They **don't write that this is PNG** or JPEG compression or what kind of compression it is - as I understood it - you load image not using OpenCV and this will convert it to Mat type image. It does not look like PNG compression. Missing working example on that page. What kind of compression is it?

Comment: `ext – File extension that defines the output format.` ... `See imwrite() for the list of supported formats and flags description.` -- same set of formats as `imwrite`.

Comment: Wait, why should I define extension when I want to encode the data to specific format like PNG and **keep it in memory**? Why I ask - I may want to send the data to database not to image file.

Comment: Because that's how it determines the format to use. It says it right there, in the documentation. My guess would be they already need to do that for `imwrite` and they reused that code here -- makes sense to me.

Comment: As for the compression parameter, I recall using that before and it did have the expected effect. Not sure why you're not seeing any difference -- perhaps you could attach a sample image to your question for us to try to reproduce this issue or explain what is happening and why.

Comment: 1950x1080 color image would be about 6MB without compression. Png can be a very good lossless compression if there are constant image regions for example.

Comment: @Micka Yeah, i was just thinking that he's already getting a decent compression, so it could be concievable zlib does a great job even with low setting.

Comment: I can save the image in Photoshop and it has 2.21MB. When I read it and save by OpenCV then it is significantly bigger and filesize does not change when I chance PNG compression value. That's odd. Also I tried this:  `vector<int> jpg; vector<int> png; bool rjpg = imencode("jpg", source, jpg, compression_params); bool rpng = imencode("png", source, png, compression_params);` I miss the clue (example) how to pass the pointer to buffer into the function.

Comment: It's supposed to be a vector of `uchar` (i.e. unsigned char, which is 1 byte), not `int` (which is signed and 4 bytes).

Comment: even with uchar it crashes

Answer (score 0):

i am not an expert on this subject but tried to test some `compression_params` maybe you will find the answer by testing the code below.

probably adding the following lines will do the trick.

```
    compression_params.push_back(IMWRITE_PNG_STRATEGY);
    compression_params.push_back(IMWRITE_PNG_STRATEGY_DEFAULT);
```

or you can try other alternatives accordind to [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#gaa60044d347ffd187161b5ec9ea2ef2f9)

also i opened an [issue](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/issues/6729)

```
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

void createAlphaMat(Mat &mat)
{
    CV_Assert(mat.channels() == 4);
    for (int i = 0; i < mat.rows; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mat.cols; ++j) {
            Vec4b& bgra = mat.at<Vec4b>(i, j);
            bgra[0] = UCHAR_MAX; // Blue
            bgra[1] = saturate_cast<uchar>((float(mat.cols - j)) / ((float)mat.cols) * UCHAR_MAX); // Green
            bgra[2] = saturate_cast<uchar>((float(mat.rows - i)) / ((float)mat.rows) * UCHAR_MAX); // Red
            bgra[3] = saturate_cast<uchar>(0.5 * (bgra[1] + bgra[2])); // Alpha
        }
    }
}

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    // Create mat with alpha channel
    Mat mat(480, 640, CV_8UC4);
    createAlphaMat(mat);

    vector<int> compression_params;
    compression_params.push_back(IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION);
    compression_params.push_back(0);
    compression_params.push_back(IMWRITE_PNG_STRATEGY);
    compression_params.push_back(IMWRITE_PNG_STRATEGY_DEFAULT);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        compression_params[1] = i;
        imwrite(format("alpha%d.png",i), mat, compression_params);
    }
    return 0;
}
```